# Manually Creating a Root Token in Vault (the hard way)

Tags: encryption, devops, hashicorp-vault, hashicorp, aws-devops

Ok so I have an application that I inherited that we do not know the root token and we do not have any recovery keys or unseal keys. The problem is, we cannot authenticate into Vault at all and we also cannot have the instance go down.

I do have access to the datastore it uses (DynamoDB) and the encrypting keys. My assumption is that it would be possible in theory to manually add an entry and set a password directly on the underlying datastore instance so that we can have a root account again.

I know this one is weird but we cannot re-initialize the database.

Any thoughts on how this could be done?

Comment: You would basically need to create a new Vault server cluster and migrate your storage backend (DynamoDB) to your new cluster. You could also upgrade the cluster for essentially the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try one of the below -

- The initial root token generated at vault operator init time -- this token has no expiration
- By using another root token; a root token with an expiration cannot create a root token that never expires
- By using vault operator generate-root (example) with the permission of a quorum of unseal key holders

Root tokens are useful in development but should be extremely carefully guarded in production. In fact, the Vault team recommends that root tokens are only used for just enough initial setup (usually, setting up auth methods and policies necessary to allow administrators to acquire more limited tokens) or in emergencies, and are revoked immediately after they are no longer needed. If a new root token is needed, the operator generate-root command and associated API endpoint can be used to generate one on-the-fly.

You can read more here - https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/tokens

Comment: I should have clarified - we have no tokens at all that I have access to including unseal keys. Some were created, but I'm not aware of how to find out what those are. If I attempt to create a new root token, it throws an error that a token generation is already in progress. I suppose the better way to phrase it is, how can I get some access in the event of all previous methods of auth out of the window.

Comment: Can you unseal the vault? then using unseal key you can create new root token - vault operator unseal & then vault operator generate-root

Comment: What can I use as the unseal key? I'm inheriting this and no copy of anything was made.

Comment: If you have lost unseal keys as well then you can't do much here - https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/issues/7640

You can try your database method but I haven't tried that before

Answer (score 2):

No matter how bad the breakup was with the previous administrator, call him and ask for the shards. Now. It's an emergency.

To create a root token, you need a quorum of shards. A shard is a large number that could be in base64. For example, this is what the same shard looks in both formats:

- 9PTUFNoCFapAvxQ2L72Iox/hmpjyHGC5PpkDj9itaMo=
- f4f4d414da0215aa40bf14362fbd88a31fe19a98f21c60b93e99038fd8ad68ca

You can mix and match formats, but each shard can be only entered once.

Run the command `vault status` to know how many different shards you need to find. The default `Threshold` is 3:

```
$ vault status
Key                      Value
---                      -----
Recovery Seal Type       shamir
Initialized              true
Sealed                   false
Total Recovery Shares    5
Threshold                3
```

If you do get your hands on some shards, enter the command `vault operator generate-root` and enter them at the prompt. Don't cancel the ongoing root token generation, if someone entered a shard some time in the past, Vault has it (even if *you* don't). `vault operator generate-root -status` will tell you if Vault already has some shards. Here is an example where the first shard of three was entered:

```
$ vault operator generate-root -status
Nonce         9f435314-ce20-4716-cea7-a083de224e4e
Started       true
Progress      1/3
Complete      false
OTP Length    26
```

If you can't find the shards, you are in trouble. You will have to find a password and read all the secrets one by one (can be scripted), ideally every version of them. You say you can't log in, so you might have to ask your user to do it.

Keep in mind that some backends (like the PKI) can't be exported manually, not even by root.